# Default remote mercurial repository in Netbeans

Tags: git, netbeans, mercurial, repository, push

Every time I want to `push` my changes to remote mercurial repository, Netbeans prompts the `Push Dialog` and asks for repository path, username and password. Is there any way I can save these things as default so I can push without being prompted?

[image: Push Dialog]

Not to mention, I have already set HG properties but it still asks me for path and credentials.

[image: HG properties]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens if you use **`Push…`**; there you have to specify where your data goes to.

Use:

- **`Push Current Branch`**, if you want to push your current branch to your default repository
- **`Push All Branches`**, if you want to do so with all your branches.

*(All in **`Mercurial -> Remote`**)*